# What is the best way to Stream multiple CCTV RTSP into Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to start to build a node.js application that is going to receive RTSP video streams from IP CCTV cameras.

I have spent considerable amount of time studying opencv and ffmpeg as the tool to listen to the cctv rtsp streams.

with opencv, I am very confused if I need to use opencv.js to be included in node script or to download and install opencv build into my os.

with ffmpeg, Im not sure if I can access the mat object (mat as in opencv) to be passed to a video processing module (such as tensorflow for object detection). When I look and tested ffmpeg RTSP examples, I cant seem to find a way to store the video buffer frames into Mat variable for processing. The video is either played on ffplay or is saved into file system.

I know this is a general questions, as I have not started coding yet.

Appreciate for some help to guide me into the right tools and methods to achieve the objective. TQ.

Comment: hi @BorneoDev did u find any solution?